# how to resize an icon in kml layer using Google Maps Api V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a question? there is someway of resize an icon in kml layer using Google Maps Api V3 ??

this is the file.kml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
   <Style id="icon05_E">
      <IconStyle>
         <Icon>
            <href>'http://190.143.101.58:3000/Images/AppIcons/Vehicles/Norte/icon051_N.png'</href>
         </Icon>
         <hotSpot x="50"  y="50" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
      </IconStyle>
   </Style>
   <Placemark>
      <name>ESTE</name>
      <styleUrl>#icon05_E</styleUrl>
      <Point>
         <coordinates>-74.03973,4.7597</coordinates>
      </Point>
   </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Thanks for your help ...

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Maps API v3 KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers) does not support the [scale](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps) tag (at present):

```
 <scale>    no
```

You could use [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) if your KML isn't very complicated.

[Example using the KML branch](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=SO_KML_resizeIcon.kml)

[Example using the KMZ branch](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=SO_KML_resizeIcon.kml)